# desperately simple python decimal

Tags: python, decimal

Hi I need some help please. I want to calculate float numbers with a format like xxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy. I have learned that I should use Decimal instead of float
I tried a lot, and I searched a lot but I still have the following simple problem:

```
    getcontext().prec = 14
    a = Decimal(str('12.737791301'))
    b = Decimal(str('12.737791839'))
    c = Decimal((b - a)) # substract is what I finally want here

    print a, b, c

12.737791301 12.737791839 5.38E-7
```

I want c to be displayed as 0.000000538

thanks for your help!

ps. normalize() did not work

Answer (score 5):

The real solution is format(), available in python 2.6 and 3.1.

`format(c,"f")` will convert the decimal to float repr-style output. This is part of the new style formatting in python.

Other worse ideas for solutions are below:

This can be accomplished with a format string, as if your Decimal values were floats.
`print "%0.9f" % c` will produce '0.000000538'

The [python library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-strings) can tell you more.

To get around the problem of needing to know the right number of decimal places, you could always print it out at the limit of float precision with a condition in case the Decimal is smaller:

```
out = "%.16f" % c if c >= 1e-16 else "0.0"
print out.rstrip('0')
```

With the second line dealing with the trailing 0s.

Comment: The problem in using `%.9f` is that you will need to know upto how many decimals you require to print and you cannot arbitrarily put a long value in the format string like `%.30f` as it gives some unexpected results...

    `>>> print %.9f %(1e-9)`

    `... '0.000000001'                          # this is correct`

    `>>> print %.30f %(1e-9)`
    `... '0.000000001000000000000000062282'     # this is not`

Dealing with floating point numbers always has some or the other problems.

Comment: This is true. There's always the ugly hack of counting digits in the exponential notation (3 in the example of 5.38E-7) and adding that to exponent - 1.

frmt = "%0." + str(3 + 7 - 1) + "f"
print frmt % c

...but such a kluge.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `quantize`. Something along the lines of

```
c_dec = Decimal(c)
NUMPLACES = Decimal(10)**( c_dec.adjusted() -3)
c_str = str( c_dec.quantize(NUMPLACES) )
print c_str
```

EDIT. In your particular example the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import decimal as dec

a = dec.Decimal(str('12.737791301'))
b = dec.Decimal(str('12.737791839'))
c = dec.Decimal((b - a)) # substract is what I finally want here

print a
print b

sign, digits, exponent=c.as_tuple()

ld=list(digits)

PREC=14
for i in range(0,exponent+PREC+1):
 ld.insert(0,0)
cstr="0."
for d in ld:
  cstr+=str(d)
print cstr
```

If you want something more robust, look up this example http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes

Comment: @azze: what exactly are you trying to achieve: have exactly 14 decimal places in the output, or three significant digits, or something else still?

Comment: I think the question was about how to format the printed string correctly, not how to round the value.